# How to return single object in django GET api (rest framework)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

I have a Table "Configuration".

```
class Configuration(models.Model):
    inventory_check = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    record_seat_number = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    base_url = models.URLField()
```

This table will have a single entry. Below is the serializer :

```
class ConfigurationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Configuration
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am using rest framework for the API. Below is the Views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_configuration(request):
     m = Configuration.objects.all()
     serializer = ConfigurationSerializer(m, many=True)
     return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This works perfectly. But the problem is this would return object inside array.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "inventory_check": false,
    "refund": true,
    "record_seat_number": false,
    "base_url": "http://localhost:8000/"
}
]
```

All I want is to send only the object without array. How to achieve this?

Comment: When you do `Configuration.objects.all()` you get a QuerySet. It converts into array in JSON. If you explicitly need only a single object, you should rethink your design. For example `Configuration.objects.get(pk=1)` will return a single object, if available.

Answer (score 3):

```
 m = Configuration.objects.get(id=1) # you need to get single object here
 serializer = ConfigurationSerializer(m) # remove many = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the many=True from the serializer instantiation:

```
 serializer = ConfigurationSerializer(m)
```